# count based on 2 fields result in 3rd

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server.  Novice.  Not sure how to phrase my question.  Try via example:

For a table with these fields and values:

```
uniqueV, state, locationcode1, locationcode2, typecode 
01, TN, 1, X
02, TN, 1, X
03, TN, 1, Y
04, KY, 2, Z
05, KY, 1, R
06, KY, 1, R
07, KY, 1, R
```

I need a result of

```
01, TN, 1, X, 2 -- e.g. 2 occurrences of 1,X in TN
02, TN, 1, X, 2
03, TN, 1, Y, 1
04, KY, 2, Z, 1
05, KY, 1, R, 3
06, KY, 1, R, 3 
07, KY, 1, R, 3
```

Where this new, 5th field is a count of the occurrences of `[typecode]` pair within each of state

========================================================

Follow-up please

Any way to produce an additional output Column with a count of a particular typecode within a State, locationcode pair.  For example a count of 'X' records

So

```
uniqueV, state, locationcode1, locationcode2, typecode 
01, TN, 1, X
02, TN, 1, X
03, TN, 1, Y
04, KY, 2, Z
05, KY, 1, R
06, KY, 1, R
07, KY, 1, R
```

resulting in

```
01, TN, 1, X, 2 -- e.g. for TN, 1 there are 2 occurances of 'X' records.
02, TN, 1, X, 2
03, TN, 1, Y, 2
04, KY, 2, Z, 0
05, KY, 1, R, 0
06, KY, 1, R, 0
07, KY, 1, R, 0
```

I thought I could extrapolate myself but was wrong :(

Comment: how did you arrive with KY,1,X?

Comment: I think they mistyped the R's as X's

Comment: Not following you.  There is no KY, 1, X.  The KY,2,Z has one occurance, is it gets a 1 in the result set.  The KY, 1, R occurs 3 times so it gets a 3 in the result set on each of the related records. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
SELECT *, 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM YourTable AS T1
WHERE T1.state = T2.state AND T1.locationcode1 = T2.locationcode1
      AND T1.locationcode2 = T2.locationcode2) AS Occur
FROM YourTable AS T2
```

Comment: `AND T1.locationcode2 = T2.locationcode2` also. OP is looking for the pair of typecodes if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: I was able to adapt this to do my follow-up.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is more efficient solution to this problem, but I think for now this can help:

```
WITH cte_base AS (
SELECT uniqueV, state, locationcode1, locationcode2,
COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY state, locationcode1, locationcode2) AS 'typecode'
FROM table_name
)
SELECT uniqueV, state, locationcode1, locationcode2, 
CASE WHEN state  = 'TN' AND locationcode1 THEN typecode 
ELSE '0' END AS 'typecode2'
FROM cte_base
```

Comment: Please see follow-up question.  Is that doable using this method?  Guess I need a "COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY state, locationcode1, locationcode2) AS 'typecode' where locationcode2='X'

Comment: My sample data has 1's and 0's in locationcode1, but the real data has thousands of different strings.  I was just trying to give a simple example.  So I can't use the location code as a Boolean.  I do have a limited number of locationcode2's (4).  What I'm after is for each record that is part of a set (state and locationcode1), to tell me the cound of each of the 3 location codes within the set.  So in each record I would have a count of how many X, how many Y, how many Z, etc. that are in that particular group/set.